# When do we need checkpoint while Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka? In ReadStream or Write Stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Kafka and PySpark+Structured Streaming and we have a requirement to stream data from a Kafka topic and ingest into another table while data undergoes multiple transformations.
I understood the concept of checkpoint, its uses and advantages. But one thing thats confusing me is what is the right place to use it?
ReadStream or WriteStream?

For example, I am reading like this:

```
def read_from_kafka(spark: SparkSession, kafka_config: dict, topic_name: str, column_schema: str, checkpoint_location: str):
    stream_df = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafka_config['broker']) \
        .option('subscribe', topic_name) \
        .option('kafka.security.protocol', kafka_config['security_protocol']) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', kafka_config['sasl_mechanism']) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', jass_config) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class', kafka_config['sasl_login_callback_handler_class']) \
        .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", kafka_config['max_offsets_per_trigger']) \
        .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
        .load() \
        .select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias("json_dta")).selectExpr('json_dta.*')
    return stream_df

stream_df = read_from_kafka(spark, config, topic_name, schema, checkpoint_location)
```

And writing the same df into some location as below.

```
def write_data(spark: SparkSession, kafka_df: DataFrame, checkpoint_location: str):
    kafka_df.writeStream \
        .format('kafka') \
        .foreachBatch(some_func) \
        .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()

def some_fun(kafka_df: DataFrame, batch_id: int):
    kafka_df.write.parquet(s'some_path_{batch_id}')
```

My confusion is do I need checkpoint at both Read & Write streams? I see some documentation where checkpoint is used only at `WriteStream()`
If I only use it in `WriteStream()` and don't use it at `ReadStream()` how can Kafka+SparkStream know from which offset of the topic should the read resume? Will there be any impact if I use it in both `ReadStream()` and `WriteStream()`?

Can anyone let me know the what is the right place to use checkpoint when reading and writing data from a Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0):

When consuming, Spark can use consumer group offset stored in Kafka itself, therefore checkpoints aren't required.

Checkpoints store state of the actions you've performed, rather than only Kafka offsets.

If it's not negatively affecting your application, then checkpoint both.

Comment: Yeah, to be on safe side, I did add checkpoint to both read & write statements. But wanted to be more clear where do we exactly need it and don't.